# Java @interface.List Groups not working within Custom constraint annotations

Tags: java, annotations, constraints, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I created a custom annotation, with an @Size.List with different constraints for different groups.

When validating a variable using this, it uses both constraints instead of the one for the group that was chosen.

However non grouped annotations work normally
Code example:

```
@Size.List({
    @Size(max = 1, groups = Group1.class),
    @Size(max = 2, groups = Group2.class) })�@OtherAnnotationsThatWork
public @interface FooAnnotation {

    String message() default “Bar”;
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}

public Class Bar{
    public Bar(String foo){ Foo = foo; }

    //doesn’t work
    @FooAnnotation
    private Foo;

    //getters and setters 
}

@Test
Private barTest(){
    Bar bar1 = new Bar(“a”);
    Validate(bar1, group1.class);

    Bar bar2 = new Bar(“bb”);
    //fails because size is greater than max of 1
    Validate(bar2, group2.class) 
}
```

I also know that this isn't caused by the @Size.List or my groups being set up incorrectly, because the following code works.

```
@OtherAnnotationsThatWork
public @interface FooAnnotation {

    String message() default “Bar”
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}

public Class Bar{
    public Bar(String foo){ Foo = foo; }

    @Size.List({
        @Size(max = 1, groups = Group1.class),
        @Size(max = 2, groups = Group2.class) })
    @FooAnnotation
    private Foo;

    //getters and setters 
}

@Test
Private barTest(){
    Bar bar1 = new Bar(“a”);
    Validate(bar1, group1.class);

    Bar bar2 = new Bar(“bb”);
    Validate(bar2, group2.class) //passes
}
```

So the question is. How do I make groups work within a custom annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the Bean Validation spec ([section 3.3](http://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#constraintsdefinitionimplementation-constraintcomposition), Constraint composition), groups on composing constraints (such as the `@Size` constraints in your example) are not considered:

> Groups from the main constraint annotation are inherited by the composing annotations. Any groups definition on a composing annotation is ignored.

I.e. your second example is the way to go.

The rationale behind this rule is to be consistent in the sense that constraint definitions themselves don't define any group memberships (and these composing constraints are part of a constraint definition).